# App Engine - How to Clear Cookie

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

I can't manage to clear the cookies in my Google app engine SDK on Mac OS. Basically every time i need to upload an app which is related to a different user I need to specify the --no_cookie flag and be redirected to an authentication page which doesn't no overwrite the existing cookie. 
I have tried by clearing up the cookies in Chrome but it seems the cookies used by app engine are stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way is to delete the

```
 /Users/<username>/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens
```

file